# How to make multiple displacements map node

Tags: texturing, uv

thanks in advance for any help.
Sort of a beginner but also not. Just haven't tried doing this before. 
So this is what I have done so far.
I took multiple images and put them in a rgb in photoshop. So now the 3 layers are over one another and I exported it as a TIFF file. 
There are 4 of the TIFF files.
So now what I want to do is to paint the 4 textures in blender onto an object. Take the unwrapped object, export it as one tiff. Back into photoshop and separate the rgb layers again to have one tiff instead of 4. 
So then once I have done that I will put it back into blender to have multiple layers to change the intensity as I would like it to be.

I truly hoped I explained it properly. My English sucks. So If you have any questions I would answer the best I can.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

the displacement Im trying to replicate from texture xyz
https://texturing.xyz/pages/making-a-digital-face-sefki-ibrahim

1) Put images into rgb and crop the mouth forehead and nose part.

[image]

2) paint onto character

[image]

3) back to photoshop to seperate the pictures

[image]

4) use as displacement in blender

thats where I am now
test it with a cube and the method worked. Now I just want to know about nodes with multi displacement.

I havent baught the displacements yet. Im doing tests to see if its possible in blender because I havent found any tutorials on this. Only in other programs so Im trying to replicate. They are expensive so I dont wanna buy something I can do nothing with.

So there will end up being 3 different displacements. I know how to put 2 but not sure with 3

Comment: Omg nm it actually worked

Comment: you can attach images to the post. Maybe it's just me, but I can't get the Idea. Why don't paint the full color image on the model, export painted texture, then separate colors? why do you want to paint separate colors to join them back again later?

Comment: I was thinking to control the different displacements separately. It worked. Now Im looking at other options. Like how to have multiple displacement maps on one object. Dont have a Image. Playing around trying to learn. Do you have any advice on multiple displacement node?

Comment: its not color . Its for displacement. My bad, should have probably say that.

Comment: I was thinking about getting a texturexyz displacement map. But there are no tutorials on how to use it in blender. So now Im trying to replicate tutorials from other programs. This was the method they used to have more control. Here is the tutorial on texture xyz. I want to test things to see if it works in blender before I buy. https://texturing.xyz/pages/making-a-digital-face-sefki-ibrahim

Comment: the thing is there are 3 diferent files you get from them. So I mixed it in photoshop using rgb. Then clop the nose, forehead and mouth region(if im correct, think there are more). Then you use those 3 TIFFs to paint onto a uv map to have them all in one. Then afterwards you take that uv into photoshop to get a final uv map with all the displacements at the same location. If you get what I mean? Then after you seperated the files in photoshop you take it back into blender to set up the displacement maps with them. Hope you get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you paint an image on the model with texture drawing, it just copies all the texture channels into your target texture. It's totally up to you, what kind of information you store in those channels. You can paint even normal maps onto a model.
If the displacement maps are just grayscale images, you mix them with add, or screen (or whatever you want) blending, and then feed the result to the Bump node (or to displacement input of the material).
You even don't need to separate the colors of your painted colored image in the photoshop - you can use 'Converter\Separate RGB' node instead, play with the levels of each channel, mix them together, and feed that mixed value to the Height input of the Bump node, or to the Displacement input of the material output node.
And images on your link are enough to play with to have an idea. If you want, you can paint some scratches with white and black brush (50% gray = no displacement) to see how it affects the look of the surface of your mesh.

Comment: Tnx for your help. Goodness I didnt even think about that and I have no idea why. Just shows what a second eye can do. Tnx again bud